# Check if file exists in sails.js

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, sails.js

I have created a sails service to load the javascript files depends on its controller name (or page and/or if there's a session).

I passed this (array of) JS files into an res.local.js and in my layout.ejs, loop it to include the js file into my html.

```
for (i = 0; i < loadJS.length; i++) {
 <script src="<%- loadJS[i] %>.js"></script>
}
```

Question, how can I check if the JS file exists before including it in my html?

In PHP, we have function called file_exists, is there a similar function with sails.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Since Sails is created with Node.js you can use [fs.exists](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback).

This will remove the file from the array if it's not found. You can load it into your view how you were before.

```
fs = require('fs');

for (i = 0; i < loadJS.length; i++) {
    fs.exists(loadJS[i], function(exists){
        if(!exists){
            //remove from array
            loadJS.splice(i, 1);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Tried to use this code but the exists always return false... but the file mostly exists...

Comment: @Nina, if the answer is correct and it works for you, please mark the answer as accepted :)